# Why does the regularity of functional procedures allow passing by value & passing by constant reference?

Tags: c++, theory

In the book Elements of Programming by Alexander A. Stepanov and Paul McJones it is stated:

> The regularity of functional procedures allows two techniques for passing inputs. When the size of the parameter is small or if the procedure needs a copy it can mutate, we pass it by value, making a local copy. Otherwise we pass it by constant reference.

Using the following definition from the book

> A procedure is regular if and only if replacing its inputs with equal objects results in equal output objects.

Let's assume there exists an object type that represents boolean values in a single word, let's call it foolean.  0 is interpreted as false, and all other states(1...n) are interpreted as true.

Now let's assume there exists a procedure that takes a foolean value and returns its representation as string of zeros and ones.

This procedure is clearly not regular as one can pass it many true values and it would return different output objects.  However I do not see how passing it an input by value or constant reference would be problematic(Other than the fact that having a data type like this would be ill-advised to begin with!).

What is it about the regularity of functional procedures as opposed to other procedures that allows for the two techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One property of a regular type is:

```
auto a = b;
assert(a==b);
```

holds; copies are equal.  You could have an irregular type that *does not* have this property; for example, `==` might check identity, and copy might create a separate identity.

In a regular procedure, we have the property that if `(a==b)`, then `f(a)` and `f(b)` have the same effect.

But `f( X const& )` doesn't do a copy, while `f( X )` *does* do a copy.  So if the type `X` is irregular in that copies are not equal, then transforming `f( X const& )` to `f( X )` can change behavior.

Now you don't need full regularity for this to hold, but this property is implied by regularity of the function and the type.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the important part there is:

> The regularity of functional procedures allows two techniques for passing inputs. **When the size of the parameter is small or if the procedure needs a copy it can mutate, we pass it by value, making a local copy. Otherwise we pass it by constant reference.**

This is actually a good practice for any function in C++.

Passing objects by value creates a copy in memory, so you really don't want to do it if the object is big and you don't *really* need a mutable copy, that's when you pass it by reference (which does not create a copy). Note that you should always prefer passing `const` references unless you really need a mutable reference (which you shouldn't).

The function being regular only assures you that when you create a copy you won't change behavior.

Also, the function you described there (with the `foolean`) **is** regular. Regularity doesn't mean that no two inputs can result in the same output. `f(1) == f(2)` doesn't mean `f` is not regular as long as `f(1)` is still the same as `f(copy(1))` (which sometimes it isn't).

Comment: Please do correct me if I'm wrong, as I'd really like to understand, but I believe the procedure I described is not regular because relies on the representation of the of the `foolean` value.  Even though 1 and 2 are both interpreted as true and therefore `1 == true` and `1 == 2`. The aforementioned procedure does not respect their equality as it returns different output values.

Comment: Relying on the representation of the `foolean` value doesn't necessarily define its regularity. A `foolean` as you described is defined by a word, the function is regular if it outputs the same results when given the same words, which does not mean it should always give different outputs when given different words. Basically, the definition from the book *doesn't require the function to be [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)*.

Comment: My mistake was in assuming that equality in the definition of a regular procedure was referring to representational equality rather than behavioural equality.  Thanks for helping me clear it up!